# ARM decompiler available for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there any iphone ARM based decompiler available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some luck with [Ida Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/). It's kind of expensive though. I'm not sure if it has ARM support, but [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) generally does well for my windows project.

(I just looked at it, and OllyDbg doesn't support ARM, but I'm leaving the link because it's still a great program.)

Comment: IDA Pro has pretty solid ARM support in the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Ida Pro is the disassembler, it translates the binary into human readable ARM assembler.
hex-rays also provides a real decompiler, which translates the disassembled code into C.